# Multiple constructors for a MYSQL procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a MYSQL procedure I've created for an inventory management program. I could solve my own problem easily enough by just creating a second procedure with a different name for the other constructor. My question is, "Is there a way, as with programming with constructors for a class, to define a separate set of instructions within the declaration of a procedure to handle the procedure differently if a different number of variables are passed to the procedure.

My current procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `addorderitem`(ord decimal,prod decimal, quant decimal)
BEGIN
DECLARE sale decimal;
SET sale = (SELECT saleprice FROM assessor.products WHERE idProducts=prod);
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
INSERT INTO orderitems (OrderNumber, idProducts, quantity, saleprice) VALUES (ord, prod, quant, sale);
END
```

The procedure adds the individual line of an order to the table of order items, retrieving the default sale price from the products table. The second constructor would be used to handle the procedure in the event that the constructor provides a sale price instead.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Stephen Coleman
Halo Media Tech

Comment: Why are you doing all of this in the database instead of the application? Applications with this level of stored procedure utilization are extremely difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is yes, but you'd likely have to use [PREPARE and EXECUTE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) to form the query as a string in your procedure and then run it.

This is necessary if you want to replace any part of the query with a variable, other than a constant scalar value.

Using dynamic SQL in stored procedures takes some care to get it right. Your motivation is to make it more convenient to code your procedures, but let me tell you that using dynamic SQL will not make coding or debugging easier. It's also not good for performance, and it opens up risks of SQL injection that can be hard to detect.

In fact, I don't recommend using stored procedures in MySQL except in rare cases. They are known to be hard to develop, hard to debug, and they have performance problems. You might be accustomed to using procedures in some other RDBMS brands such as Oracle or Microsoft SQL Server, but you should know that MySQL's implementation of stored procedures is primitive and inefficient compared to those other brands.